# Define sys path to be considered by python script under crontab

Tags: linux, python, cron, crontab

Consider you have the following crontab definition:

```
* * * * * /home/dan/test.py
```

Consider you have the path `/home/dan/foo/`,  where `foo` directory holds a python module named `foo`.

Whereas `test.py` looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/dan')
from foo.foo1 import Foo1
```

This is how all working well, but now I want to pass the path definition into cron, and I did the following:

1. Commented out `sys.path.append('/home/dan')` in `test.py`
2. Added to crontab this definition above the cronjob config:

   ```
   PATH=/home/dan
   ```

And it's not working. Any idea why?

Comment: You probably need more the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable than the `PATH` one

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
PYTHONPATH='/home/dan' python /home/dan/test.py
```